# Is JSON RPC over TLS secure enough?

Tags: php, security, ssl, json-rpc

I intend to have a PHP web service accepting JSON-RPC over TLS (HTTPS). Every client will have an API key that I will use for identification purposes. Is that enough security, is there a JSON-RPC security specific standard?

Comment: I read about tls and i see that it would provide enough security against eavesdroping and consistence of the message so what i am looking on the ws side is mainly authenticity (alice is alice and definetely not bob)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a fine way of doing things. Here's an overview of the requirements and components play in your security scheme:

### Checklist

Here's the checklist of what security is needed, and how you would address it:

- A third party can't eavesdrop on your communications. HTTPS provides this.
- A third party can't tamper with your communications. HTTPS provides this too.
- The client can authenticate the server. HTTPS provides this (*).
- The server can authenticate the client.

### Client authentication

There are lots of way to authenticate the client. Here are a few exaples:

- **Use the API key to calculate an HMAC of the request and include the HMAC as a header in the request**. (**) The most secure, but more complicated to set-up. The key advantage is that should your server be compromised, API keys won't be exposed.
- **Include the API key itself in the request**.  Easier to set-up, may be sufficient security depending on your requirements.
- ...

---

(*): So long as the client library does. HTTPS requires that you use a certificate that validates your site corresponds to the domain name. Unfortunately, many HTTPS libraries do not validate this by default.
(**): You should also use a nonce to prevent against replay attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You could be signing a request using a secret salt (+hashing algo of choise, MD5 will do fine) because this way an eavesdropper cannot obtain the "API key" and forge his own requests. Use a very long salt.

The salt also acts to protect against intentional altering of a message by a successfull eavesdropper.

How can there be a man in a middle? TLS(SSL) is not much security against man in the middle attacks, unless you issue whitelisted certificates per client. For example, the server in the middle (attacker) obtains valid certificates, or the client application is not checking for various certificate validity settings (expiration dates, etc.). If not under your control, it is likely that clients of your RPC server will connect without doing any sort of security checks. This is a widespread problem. **Eavesdropping usually implies access to your (or your client's) network so this could mean poisoned DNS traffic redirects to the rogue server**.

Wether your or your client's network connection is secure enough to exclude the possibility of DNS poisoning, or your client is checking the certificates for validity, or you force the client to use whitelisted SSL certificates, are things only you can influence or decide upon.

You might also want to prevent replay attacks by assigning a unique number for each request (possibly overkill if these API calls are just for reading) for denying duplicate requests.

The API keys you mentioned, are generally used when browser side JavaScript clients are involved to track usage. API keys are reissued, when stolen, to identify and disable unauthorized apps (and maybe automatically make a list of the fraudulent domain names for further [lawsuit] action).

Comment: Be careful when making edits to your post - you just removed a couple of corrections!

Comment: What is a secret salt if not a key? MD5 really is not fine for signing. Using an hashing algorithm alone isn't going to protect against hash extension attacks (you should use HMAC). HTTPS does protect against MITM, although many client libraries do not implement that security.

Comment: Yes, many client libraries (and mostly client custom code) don't enable strict enough security for SSL. That's what I said in the answer. A secret salt is not the type of key Fabio was refering to. "API key" usually means client id (again, as I explained in my post), not a password, and it certainly does not imply hashing.

Comment: My post explored how JSON RPC over TLS can be insecure, because the question is: 
"Is JSON RPC over TLS secure enough". Also I don't see how your comment relates to my answer or the question. Your comment is negated automatically by my answer.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan My comment was meant to pinpoint specific parts of your answer with which I disagreed, hoping that you could clarify (e.g. What is that "secret salt"?) or correct (HMAC + SHA1,256) is more appropriate than MD5 here). I'm not offering a rebuttal of your entire answer, which I find fine overall.

Comment: How will a hash extension attack ever be successfull or needed? Hash extension attacks only work when the salt is known. If the salt is known, why would anyone ever need to do a hash extension (the attacker just has to recompute the hash)? (for our scenario).

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan If you do `Signature = Hash(Salt + Msg)`, you are exposed to an hash extension attack even though the attacker may not know the salt. That's one of the reasons why HMAC is to be used for signatures (and using a "secret" usually has to do with signatures). Nevertheless, you are free to think HMAC is useless and that you know better and use MD5 - you can have your opinion, and I can have mine. Let me however recommend against it.

Comment: I don't see how this is about opinions. Hash extension attacks aim to add data while keeping the same MD5 hash. However, if the MD5 hash is obtained using a secret salt, the attacker cannot possibly know the MD5 hash which will result from md5(secret salt+new data) when checking for alterations at destination. Alternatively, if the salt is not secret, there's no need to do an extension attack. So leave extension attacks out of this discussion, they do not apply to any scenario.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan Look, I'm not going to keep arguing about this much longer. I however humbly suggest that you read up what [an hash extension attack is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack), because, contrary to what you think, you **do not re-use the same hash in that scenario**, you **compute a new one from the initial one**. You're confusing **collisions** with **extensions**, and that's the very reason why you should stick to the standards and use HMAC, not some insecure cryptosystem you came up with.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco It seems you're the one who needs educating here. Go read about it. You are so wrong. These attacks add data while keeping the same hash. First Google result for you: http://blog.whitehatsec.com/hash-length-extension-attacks/

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan Straight from your own link: `http://example.com/download?file=report.pdf&mac=563162c9c71a17367d44c165b84b85ab59d036f9` vs `http://example.com/download?file=report.pdf%80%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00
%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00
%00%A8/../../../../../../../etc/passwd&amp;mac=ee40aa8ec0cfafb7e2ec4de20943b673968857a5`. Did you even **read what you linked?** Do these two MACs look **remotely similar** to you? Look, I'm not trying to make a fool of you, that would be great if you could realize this.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan This site is about learning new things. This is not supposed to be a conflict between you and me. I'm sorry if you feel offended in any way, but I would appreciate if we could just call it a day now.

Comment: Since that would have been a JSON string, yes. This type of attack only allows appending data. For the RPC we are talking about, the JSON string is a serialized object or array. Any JSON deserializer will either ignore the appended data (which comes after the final } or ]), or throw a syntax error. So no vulnerability there. Again, this type of attack does not apply, don't bring it up again. Thanks.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan Look, you seem to believe that anything I say is, (like myself,) *so wrong*. Therefore, I don't feel like this discussion is going anywhere, so I'll leave it here. Best of luck in the future.

Comment: If you can't admit it (the attack does not apply to this scenario), then please don't leave these lengthly good bye comments, they really don't add anything to this conversation. See ya.

Comment: Actually, in JSON-RPC < 2.0 (this changed since!), some servers would accept several RPC calls in a single HTTP request, although they do not form a single object. You're right in saying this is a bit of an edge case though!

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks. You are refering to jsonrpc.org? I for one have built my own JSON based RPC server and client for my apps (reinvented the wheel to allow for quite a lot of stuff).